# Get the form details after being redirected to paypal page

Tags: php, paypal

I want to get the details form the paypal form. I redirect my clients to this form after they select a certain amount. Can i get the details of the form below? 
I am not sure. Since paypal is asking for the creditcard number and all that, for security purposes it should not allow to get this form data. But again, just wondering, is it possible?

[image]

Comment: Take a look at PayPal IPN - https://www.paypal.com/ipn or PayPal PDT - https://www.paypal.com/pdt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Certainly not using PHP (going by your tags here), which is server side, and this would be a javascript hack. The way that immediately leapt to mind would be to invoke Javascript in a child iframe that contained the Paypal form, but there are two immediately apparent problems with that:

1. I doubt Paypal would allow that page to be opened in an iframe
2. You can't invoke javascript in an iframe if the page in that frame is not on the same domain as the calling page.

The best way I can think of to achieve this would be to make a Greasemonkey/Chrome/whatever extension using javascript to fish the data and send it off, but then there's this: **No-one will willingly install something that they know to steal credit card information on their computer.** Why on earth do you want to do this?

On a related, though unhelpful note, if you are interested in trying this for a purpose that is less illegal and immoral, one thing you might want to look at is [this](http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=109). It shows how to do cross-domain communication using frames if you have permission to write javascript on both pages (or have found an unsanitised field to inject it with)...

Comment: and is it possible to redirect the user to a particular page on payment success and to another page on payment failed??

Comment: That's where instant payment notification comes in. There's a PHP code sample (and others) on this page: https://www.x.com/developers/PayPal/documentation-tools/code-sample/216623